# Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, rdlc, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2017

I am [Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) and NuGet `ReportViewerControl.Winform` package.

Now it is possible to open *.rdlc file in Visual Studio 2017 designer, but when i try to save my report i am getting error: **"Unknown Report Version: 9.0**

Also, i can't create empty *.rdlc file because don't have the same template in *New File...* dialog

[image]

---

**UPD:**

At `this` moment, i have no idea how to fix that, but i know hwo to **avoid** it:

Open your `old` report in **VS2015** and then save it - next time **VS2017** can open/edit/save files.

Comment: Quote: *Report issues with Vsix Package or Designer to: RvcFeedback@Microsoft.com*

Comment: thank you, but it's useless right now, they know about this trouble and worked to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from `marketplace`:

> This happens when you have missed a reference. Please search through
>   all of your code and project files to find the 9.0 references and
>   update to 14.0.
>
> By Sql Reporting Services 25.04.2017

It means that you need to search for **patterns (previous xml structure) of 9.0 version** in your *.rdlc  file, *which was not obvious for me*.

That is why resave in VS2015 worked.

Comment: So, I've searched, there is no 9.0 in any project file and still get the error

Answer (score 2):

I have found that opening SSRS 2005 layouts from the Solution Explorer causes this error. If I close Visual Studio, open File Explorer, find the .RDLC and double-click on it top open VS 2017 without the project loaded, I can convert and save the file. Once it’s converted and saved, I can work with it normally inside VS.

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded an old project from VS2005 to VS2017 and all of the reports displayed as XML. After adding the Rdlc Report Designer Extension, it would ask me to convert them when I tried to open them and I could view them in design-mode but I couldn't save them without getting this error. Closing the project and opening the rdlc files one at a time in Visual Studio allowed the conversion to work properly and then I could open/save them from within the project.